# Intel SSD as a system drive in a new Unibody Macbook 13"

Tags: ssd, macbook

Can I replace the built-in 5400 rpm hdd with Intel X25-M G2 80GB in a new Unibody Macbook 13" (or in a new Macbook Pro 13") and have it work as a system drive with Mac OS X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most certainly can! Of course, you would need to install OS X from it's install disc to get it up and running.

Answer (score 4):

but of course. it [has been done](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3V3BGBtKqf8) before :)